# Legal Hold Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

Does Legal Hold monitor specific things to ensure that everything in a mailbox is tracked when it is enabled?

Comment: Care to expand on this question a bit further, or is this a homework question?

Comment: I don't know what elements you're referring to.  A legal hold just ensures that users can't delete items from a mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much which two elements it's tracking as overall tracking. A good write-up of what Legal Hold does can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861123%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx). The Hold process leverages the Recoverable Items folder to maintain a log of activity in the mailbox. Certain user-actions trigger retention activities.

- **Deletes**. When a user deletes a message (empties the trash) the messages are stored in the Recoverable Items folder directly.
- **Purges**. When a user removes an item from Recoverable Items directly, a copy of the purged message is stored. For mailboxes not in legal-hold status this would normally fully delete the message.
- **Changes**. When information in a message changes, such as subject lines, categories, flags, and other user-modifiable items, a copy of the pre-change message is archived. This provides a full change-log for eDiscovery later.

Legal-hold overrides the system defaults for retention in Recoverable Items.

Comment: I've edited the question.  I don't think it affects your answer any, but you might want to once over it...